# android app not working on lower versions

Tags: java, android, android-install-apk

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 28
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.example.ananduamenon.a2z_final"
        minSdkVersion 23
        targetSdkVersion 28
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
        testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:28.0.0'
    implementation 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.1.3'
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test:runner:1.0.2'
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.0.2'
    implementation 'com.android.support:cardview-v7:28.0.0'
    implementation 'com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:28.0.0'
    implementation 'com.android.support:support-v4:28.0.0'
    implementation 'com.android.support:design:28.0.0'
    implementation 'com.android.support:support-annotations:28.0.0'
    implementation 'com.android.volley:volley:1.1.1'

}
```

how can I run the app in the lower version? 
I tried changing version but gets too many errors. help............................................................................

```
01-15 15:11:47.695 14480-14480/com.example.ananduamenon.a2z_final W/ResourceType: Failure getting entry for 0x7f07005e (t=6 e=94) (error -75)
01-15 15:11:47.697 14480-14480/com.example.ananduamenon.a2z_final E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    Process: com.example.ananduamenon.a2z_final, PID: 14480
    java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.example.ananduamenon.a2z_final/com.example.ananduamenon.a2z_final.Activity.LoginActivity}: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #57: Binary XML file line #57: Error inflating class Button
        at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2560)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2626)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap11(ActivityThread.java)
        at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1475)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:111)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:207)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5740)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:905)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:766)
     Caused by: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #57: Binary XML file line #57: Error inflating class Button
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:539)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:423)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:374)
        at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDelegateImpl.setContentView(AppCompatDelegateImpl.java:469)
        at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity.setContentView(AppCompatActivity.java:140)
        at com.example.ananduamenon.a2z_final.Activity.LoginActivity.onCreate(LoginActivity.java:47)
        at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:6543)
        at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1113)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2513)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2626) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap11(ActivityThread.java) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1475) 
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:111) 
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:207) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5740) 
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:905) 
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:766) 
     Caused by: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #57: Error inflating class Button
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:782)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:704)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:835)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflateChildren(LayoutInflater.java:798)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:838)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflateChildren(LayoutInflater.java:798)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:838)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflateChildren(LayoutInflater.java:798)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:515)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:423) 
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:374) 
        at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDelegateImpl.setContentView(AppCompatDelegateImpl.java:469) 
        at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity.setContentView(AppCompatActivity.java:140) 
        at com.example.ananduamenon.a2z_final.Activity.LoginActivity.onCreate(LoginActivity.java:47) 
        at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:6543) 
        at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1113) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2513) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2626) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap11(ActivityThread.java) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1475) 
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:111) 
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:207) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5740) 
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:905) 
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:766) 
     Caused by: android.content.res.Resources$NotFoundException: Resource "com.example.ananduamenon.a2z_final:drawable/button_background" (7f07005e) is not a Drawable (color or path): TypedValue{t=0x1/d=0x7f07005e a=-1 r=0x7f07005e}
        at android.content.res.Resources.loadDrawableForCookie(Resources.java:2842)
        at android.content.res.Resources.loadDrawable(Resources.java:2764)
        at android.content.res.TypedArray.getDrawable(TypedArray.java:870)
        at android.view.View.<init>(View.java:4001)
        at android.widget.TextView.<init>(TextView.java:702)
        at android.widget.Button.<init>(Button.java:109)
        at android.widget.Button.<init>(Button.java:105)
        at android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatButton.<init>(AppCompatButton.java:71)
        at android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatButton.<init>(AppCompatButton.java:67)
        at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatViewInflater.createButton(AppCompatViewInflater.java:187)
        at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatViewInflater.createView(AppCompatViewInflater.java:110)
        at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDelegateImpl.createView(AppCompatDelegateImpl.java:1266)
        at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDelegateImpl.onCreateView(AppCompatDelegateImpl.java:1316)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:746)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:704) 
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:835) 
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflateChildren(LayoutInflater.java:798) 
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:838) 
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflateChildren(LayoutInflater.java:798) 
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:838) 
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflateChildren(LayoutInflater.java:798) 
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:515) 
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:423) 
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:374) 
        at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDelegateImpl.setContentView(AppCompatDelegateImpl.java:469) 
        at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity.setContentView(AppCompatActivity.java:140) 
        at com.example.ananduamenon.a2z_final.Activity.LoginActivity.onCreate(LoginActivity.java:47) 
        at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:6543) 
        at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1113) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2513) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2626) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap11(ActivityThread.java) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1475) 
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:111) 
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:207) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5740) 
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:905) 
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:766) 
01-15 15:11:47.703 14480-14480/com.example.ananduamenon.a2z_final I/Process: Sending signal. PID: 14480 SIG: 9
```

Comment: what versions ? There is nothing magical, you need to provide error logs and most probably adapt your code to use compatibility libraries provided by Android to be able to run your app on lower Android versions

Comment: its works fine in oreo. but cant even instal in android 6 or below

Comment: please read my comment and answer it if you want help

Comment: attach your xml file in which you are getting error.

Comment: Looks like you are using a non supported `style` for `Button`  for that particular API level . Check the entry of `button_background` in default drawable folder. it should be there .

Answer (score 0):

minSdkVersion is what controlling the old versioning here.

Change the

```
minSdkVersion 23
```

To whatever you want like 21 if you want your app to support devices up to lollipop version. Normally these days developers are using minSdkVersion 21. If you are getting any error you can fix them easily.

Hope this will give you proper guidance.

Answer (score 0):

> Activity.LoginActivity}: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML
>   file line #57: Binary XML file line #57: Error inflating class Button
>
> Caused by: android.content.res.Resources$NotFoundException: Resource
>   "com.example.ananduamenon.a2z_final:drawable/button_background"
>   (7f07005e) is not a Drawable

I think you need to read *error stack trace* closer. As I see, you used some **button_background** that unsatisfied inflating property (drawable/color). I recommend to you check your **button_background.xml** file and figure out what you write wrong.

Answer (score 0):

Have you by any chance defined a separate resource (drawable, layout) file for older Android versions? 
Your stack trace tells that it cannot inflate a button due to a missing drawable.

Answer (score 0):

```
minSdkVersion 23
```

set it to the lower version like         `minSdkVersion 19`

and in your code check about the version if it lower than 23 implements another scenario or disable the feature like :

```
if (android.os.Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.M) {
           // implement your logic here
        } else {
            // implement another scenario or disable this feature 
        }
```